# Mongoose post save hook , update the document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hook

I am using a mongoose post save hook to make an API call. I want to save the response from that API back to the same doc that was uploaded to the MongoDB.

```
UserSchema.post("save", async function (doc, next) {
  try {
    //This is the API call that gets fired and returns some data
    let data = await new sendDocToAPI(doc).send();
    //the data contains a exampleID which i want to save in exampleIDField.
    //I have predefined this exampleIDField field in the schema.
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("get -> error", error);
    next(error);
  }
});
```

I have tried multiple approaches such as using *this.constructor.updateOne* or using the same doc to update *doc.updateOne*. None of them seems to work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should be able to use `doc.exampleIDField = data.exampleID; doc.save();` but this might cause an infinite loop since you are saving the doc again and it might trigger the post save hook agaian. So you may want to check if exampleIDField exists and if so don't save it or even call the api

Comment: Yeah, this sounds good. But can I update the doc? I don't have an update post hook. Or help me understand even on the update of the doc my save post hook gets invoked ??

Answer (score 1):

After playing around for an hour I found this solution working.
It doesn't modify the document you received after you saved it, but it triggers the new call to the model passed to .model() function and updates the document by criteria (id) with the data you want.

```
UserSchema.post("save", async function (doc, next) {
  try {
    let data = await doc
      .model("User")
      .findOneAndUpdate({ _id: doc._id }, { exampleIDField: "some ID you want to pass" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("get -> error", error);
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: I cannot use finOneAndUpdate but I can use updateOne, thank for your help.